# install mongodb on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mongodb

I wanna install mongodb
I follow the tutorial but when I use `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`
return this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-server : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-shell : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
N: Ignoring file 'mongodb-org' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the guide from this [page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), the `mongodb-org` package does not have a dependency to `libssl1.1`, only to `libssl3`.

Are you sure, that you chose the right repository for Jammy(22.04) and not Focal(20.04) or even Bionic(18.04)? Because Focal and Bionic offer only `openssl1.1`, which would explain the wrong/missing dependencies.

See dependency graph:

[image]